# Dogfooding and Jobs - what's with SE using an external jobs portal and... not their own?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, jobs

I've gotten back into the habit of checking the ["work here"](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here) page on Stack Overflow, partially because it's a good way to read the tea leaves on the direction of the company.

It has, as far back as I remember, always been a *discrete* part of the network, separate from careers/Jobs, with its own application system.

I've noticed the [Glassdoor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glassdoor) link at the bottom, but there also seems to be a link to something called "[TheMuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Muse_(website))". What's conspicuously missing is Stack Overflow...

[image: Glassdoor link and TheMuse links]

Considering that the "work here" page has essentially been a semi-internal portal of sorts, and Stack Exchange are using their jobs platform for jobs beyond the developerverse, it seems... odd that it is not listed in their own jobs portal, and uses a third party one.

So - *Why* TheMuse, and would Stack Overflow consider dogfooding their own product as an additional way to advertise openings?

Comment: My takes is Jobs, while the original business idea, has had a rocky history at SE, and it’s not seen as a core product. They had another round of layoffs in that careers sales team recently.

Comment: Might as well be that those layoffs were all across the board in order to survive till the series E funding was secured.

Comment: Is it possible that these are non-technical job listings, which aren't a good fit on Stack Overflow Jobs?

Comment: Currently 2 dev jobs and one PM at least

Comment: Out of curiosity I looked at other job sites and while both LinkedIn and Indeed use their own product, Dice and Monster do not.

Answer (score -3):

We are currently listing 2 open roles using our own [Work Here](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here/) page. As far as I can tell, the plan is to continue to do that. The current community roles we're hiring for are:

- [VP of Community Management](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here/3131115/vice-president-of-community-management)
- [Community Manager, Curator Support Team](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here/3049910/community-manager-curator-support-team)

You can also check the page for other positions we have available.

Comment: Oh, I knew about that - I was referring to careers but.. that's soon to be moot?

Comment: Yeah, bit anachronistic *now*, but I'm pretty sure when this question was written it was referring to Talent/Jobs/Company Pages as the "dogfood" that wasn't being eaten (note both of the linked jobs are on LinkedIn). Of course, that dogfood is going away, so whatever observations might have once been derived from its consumption are no longer applicable; I'd suggest this question is obsolete.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yes, this will soon be moot as of [Prashanth's announcement](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/04/07/an-update-on-our-product-led-saas-transformation/).